# Rails, TypeError: can't modify frozen object, only in Development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

So I have these two lines:

```
@unTaggedPhotos = Photo.cached_unTagged.sort_by{rand}[0..7]
```

which calls:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('unTagged', :expires_in => 20.minutes) {Photo.where("hide = 0").limit(300)}
```

And the first time I load a page after clearing the cache it works, but then I get the frozen object error.

The weird thing is this does not seem to be a problem on the live version of my site running the same code. (I have other things cached that work on the local version too)

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: At the first line of code I quoted.

Comment: Please post your `config/development.rb` and `config/production.rb` files and any other files where you configure your cache settings.

Comment: From development.rb:  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
and from production.rb   config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle the problem, but when I break it into two steps and call ruby's dup method when referencing the cached data it doesn't complain about being frozen anymore.

```
myUTP = Photo.cached_unTagged.dup
@unTaggedPhotos = myUTP.sort_by{rand}[0..7]
```